# perl match multiple numbers from a variable similar to egrep

Tags: regex, perl

Want to match the number exactly from the variable which has multiple numbers seperated by pipe symbol similar to egrep.below is the code which i tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $searchnum = $ARGV[0];

my $num = "148|1|0|256";
print $num;

if ($searchnum =~ /$num/)
{
    print "found";
}
else
{
    print "not-found";
}
```

Expected o/p

```
perl number_match.pl 1
found
perl number_match.pl 1432
not-found
```

Comment: Your code is working with the given set of numbers, didn't got your que, do you want to make it generic?.

Comment: @ashu when i run perl number_match 1432 its returning found, i am supposed to get not-found, i want to match the whole number say example 1 should match 1 not 148 since 1 is available in 148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `/148|1|0|256/` matches if the string that this regex is bound to contains a substring that is either `148`, `1`, `0` or `256`. This means that the option `148` is superfluous, as this matches a subset of strings that match `1`.

You probably want to test if the given string is equal to one of these options. If you want to use regexes, you have to anchor the regex at the start and the end of the string:

```
/^ (?:148|1|0|256) $/x
```

You could also use the `grep` builtin:

```
my $number = ...;
if (grep {$number eq $_} qw/148 1 0 256/) { say "found"     }
else                                      { say "not-found" }
```

The `grep` function takes a block that has to return a boolean value. It returns all elements from the list on the right where the condition returns true. If at least one element matches, then the whole expression evaluates to true.

You could also use a hash that contains all possible options:

```
my $number = ...;
my %options = map { $_ => undef } qw/148 1 0 256/;
if ( exists $options{$number} ) { say "found"     }
else                            { say "not-found" }
```

This is more efficient than `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
my $num = '^(148|1|0|256)$';
```

Here is a oneliner:

```
perl -e "$_=$ARGV[0]; exit if !/^\d+$/; print \"not-\" unless /^(14|156|0|89)$/;print \"found\n\";"
```

Comment: That won't even compile — `$"` is the list seperator for array interpolation.

Comment: @amon Correct, it should be backslashed or single quote, I will edit it

Comment: Here is a oneliner: >> perl -e "$_=$ARGV[0]; exit if !/^\d+$/; print \"not-\" unless /^(14|156|0|89)$/;print \"found\n\";"  14

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks for the edit, I was just reading in Meta how to properly post a commnet with code!